# Can someone show me how to prove that $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is onto if and only if it has a right inverse?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, inverse

$f:X \rightarrow Y$ is onto if and only if it has a right inverse: that is, a function $g:Y \rightarrow X$ such that $f \circ g = 1_y$

Comment: This question is missing context or work.  Do you have any thoughts on the problem?  If $f$ is, indeed, onto, how could you define $g$?  If $f$ is not onto, how can you prove that $g$ can't exist?  Also, the title of the question should be informative (right now, the answer to your question is "yes" someone can prove this, but that's likely not what you meant).

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean the map of sets. If $f: X\to Y$ is onto then for any $y\in Y$ there exists $x\in X$ such that $f(x) = y$. Choose for every $y\in Y$ such an $x$ and call it $x_y$. Define $g:Y\to X$ as $g(y) = x_y$. It obviously follows that $(f\circ g) (y) = y$.

If there exists a right inverse $g:Y\to X$ then for any $y\in Y$ take $x = g(y)\in X$. Since $f\circ g = 1_Y$ $f(x) = f(g(y)) = y$ and hence $f$ is onto.